# mongodb 3.0.3 export json - creates Number() wrapper around number

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-pig

In mongodb 3.0.3 while export json 
- creates Number() wrapper around number in json output

This is causing the JSON to be invalid and I cant load it in PIG using ElephantBird JSONLoader. If I remove the Number() wrapper , ElephantBird JSONLoader can read it perfectly.

Is there any way to remove the Number() wrapper in json export data?

Comment: I have not solved this error. For now, I am enclosing Number() as "Number()" to convert it to json String so that parsing succeds.

Comment: Can't you load it into PIG using [`MongoLoader`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage#from-a-mongodb-collection)?

Comment: What are you using to export JSON? `mongoexport`?

Comment: MongoLoader wont scale to load data  as I m using single node for Mongo while I have a large Hadoop cluster . Yes I m using mongoexport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is bug in Windows mongoexport - creates Number() wrapper around number in json output.On Linux, mongoexport json works fine